# LibGDX is an executable JAR file but will not run when selected

Tags: java, java-8, libgdx, installation

I have installed Java version 8 and then proceeded to install libgdx. Once installed I tried to open it but it will not run and appear with the project generator page. The icon is a blank document and doesn't show the Java symbol. I have followed tutorials but for some reason it's just not working. I have changed the environment variables. I'm just confused as to why it won't work. I have followed the following tutorial exactly how it is but I installed version 8 and I did not install the Android related things but that shouldn't have made a difference?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huifd-C2KrI

Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong and help?

Thanks

Comment: try to run using cmd `java -jar gdx-setup.jar`

Comment: Thank You!!This worked. How come you have to type that in?